# VB windows forms app using sqllocaldb Login fails on non development computer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, deployment

I have created a Visual Basic 2013 app that accesses sqllocaldb 2014.  It performs correctly for me and another test user on my development machine whether in the IDE or run from disc.  I have created a setup program.

To install in on another machine, I install sqlocaldb, make the data folder, put the .mdf and.ldf in the folder and run the install program.  I get login failed for every user I try it for when it accesses a stored procedure.  I have some code that downloads data from an access table and writes it to the sqlocaldb and this code runs without the database login failure.

I created a whole series of app back in 2016 in VS 2013 c# that use sqllocaldb 2012.  The above install method I have used literally hundreds of times and it works fine for any user that logs on the machine.  I do not remember having this problem on that series of programs.

I have added "NT SYSTEM\Authenticated users" as a login and a user and made them `db_owner`.

This is my connection string

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\MYDB\MYDBReporting.mdf;Initial Catalog=MYDBReporting;Integrated Security=True
```

Is there a guide on how to do this?

Comment: So you have some code that works and some code that does not. Have you tried to comparing the two to see where the difference may be?

Comment: The code for my present project works on the development machine and not production machines.   It's the same code.  I have closely perused the old app that works and as fare as I can tell everything is the same.

Comment: Dim taDelCurrentBen As New HRTReportingDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter
        taDelCurrentBen.usp_DeleteCurrentBen()


is the actual code that causes the error.  I think it is a setting in the sqllocaldb, but I have compared settings again and again and not found it.

Comment: This may help: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename and this: https://forums.asp.net/t/1969559.aspx?connection+string+of+Local+DB+file

Answer (score 1):

A Crystal reports error led me to look closely at the Crystal setup.  The client in this case wants the reports stored on the server so everyone is using the exact same report.  My old app kept them local.  The login failure was from the server residing Crystal Reports back to the sqllocaldb.  The solution was to deploy SQL Server Express on the server and use that as a data source for the Crystal reports and the app.